# Using line integrals and Green formula to calculate force?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, vectors

A force field $F$ = -y$^2$I$+x$j acts on a particle which moves on a closed loop formed by the sides of a triangle with vertices at $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,2)$ in the anticlockwise direction. Find the work done by the force field in two ways.

a)By taking the appropriate line integral

b)By using Greens formula

> I'm assuming the parametrisation is a quarter circle of radius 2, as that's the only shape which would cover the triangle 
>   $$r(t) = (2\cos(t), 2\sin(t)), t \in [0,{\pi/2}]$$
>   I have no idea how to do the Greens formula method

Comment: You have to paramatrize the actual tringle, not some other unrelated shape. Your parametrization will have three pieces, one for each of the lines making up the triangle. Does that help?

Comment: As for Green's theorem, given a region $R$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the theorem says that $\oint_{\delta R} F \cdot ds  = \iint_R \text{Curl}(F)dA$.

Comment: Yes it does help, I have an example in my lecture notes on how to calculate the parameterisation of 3 paths but it is very difficult to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two points $P$ and $Q$ you can parametrize the line between them by $r(t) = P + t(Q-P)$ for $t\in[0,1]$, this has the orientation going from $P$ to $Q$.

In your example you have three points, $P=(0,0),Q=(1,0)$ and $R= (0,2)$. You should draw the triangle that these points define and observe that the anti-clockwise direction starting at $P$ goes to $R$ and then to $Q$ and then back to $P$.

Given the vector field $F = (-y^2,x)$ the circulation of $F$ round the triangle $$\oint_{\text{triangle}} F\cdot ds$$
Can be computed as the sum of the three integrals
$$ \int_{\vec{PR}} F\cdot ds + \int_{\vec{RQ}} F\cdot ds + \int_{\vec{QP}} F\cdot ds$$

I'll do the first one for you. As I noted above $\vec{PR}$ can be parametrised by $r(t) = P + t(R-P) = (0,0) + t((0,2)-(0,0)) = (0,2t)$ for $t\in[0,1]$. So then
$$
\int_{\vec{PR}} F\cdot ds = \int_0^1 F(r(t)) \cdot r'(t) \, dt = \int_0^1 (-(2t)^2,0)\cdot(0,2) \, dt = \int_0^1 0 \, dt =0
$$
Note that this makes sense, because the path $\vec{PR}$ moves along the $y$-axis and as you move along the $y$ axis your direction of motion is perpendicular to the direction of $F$, so $F$ can do no work on you as you move along the $y$-axis.

Can you do the other two from here?

Comment: Yes in the end doing all three paths, and then doing Green's formula afterwards I have gained the answer 7/3 both times - thank you.